# Jquery conflict in Mangeto 1.9

Tags: magento

Hi we are using the following extension from https://store.plumrocket.com/magento-extensions/product-filter-magento-extension.html to allows us to add custom filters. But their appears to be some jquery conflicting with it.

I am quite new to magento and not sure what to do to resolve the conflicts I have looked in the  appears to be a conflict at the min can someone help out the site in question is http://indiefude.com/.
 t

Comment: Unable to see your site - "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable indiefude.com"

Comment: @Eugene dam i forgot you can only see it if you log in admin

Comment: Are you using noconflict for your jQuery?